# How to display a three column small table nicely in a single column page?

Tags: tables

The table does not look nice on the entire page. How do I make it a bit nicer to minimise the blank space around it?

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
%\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx, ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
% For tables use
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Comparison between smartphone and MPU+MCU based monitoring}
\label{swa_tab:2}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabularx}
                {\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}
                            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}
                             }
\toprule
\thead{Features} &\thead{ Smartphone} & \thead{MCU+MPU}\\
\midrule\\
\textbf{Device Type} & General purpose & Dedicated \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Cost} & High~(US\$100 or more) &  Low~(US\$10 or less)\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Form Factor} & 6-7 inches & 2-3 inches\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Power Consumption} & More than 5 watt & less than 1 watt\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Device Integration} &Very Difficult& Easy to integrate\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Ease of use}& Difficult for seniors & Easy for seniors\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Durability \& parts} & Fragile\&costly spare & Durable\&Cheap\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Half page length will be ideal

Comment: If you don't use an `X` column there is no point in using a `tabularx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since none of the cell contents are particularly long, I suggest using an ordinary `tabular` environment. Oh, and don't overdose on **bold-facing** stuff. A well-designed table doesn't require it; in fact, **bold-facing** can quickly become a needless distraction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,
  chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
%% I've kept the preamble purposefully sparse
\usepackage{booktabs, array, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Comparison between smartphone and MPU+MCU based monitoring}
\label{swa_tab:2}       % Give a unique label

\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l @{}}
\toprule
Features & Smartphone & MCU+MPU \\
\midrule
Device type & General purpose & Dedicated \\

Cost & High~(US\$100 or more) &  Low~(US\$10 or less)\\

Form Factor & 6--7 inches & 2--3 inches\\

Power consumption & More than 5 Watt & less than 1 Watt\\

Device integration &Very difficult& Easy to integrate\\

Ease of use & Difficult for seniors & Easy for seniors\\

Durability \& parts & Fragile \& costly spare & Durable \& cheap\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Using `tabularx` with no `X` column is not going to work.
2. If your table has three columns, don't allocate four of them.
3. This is stylistic, but boldface has no real place in tables like this one.
4. `\noalign{\smallskip}\hline` is wrong, use `\bottomrule`.
5. Numeric ranges should be `6--7`, with an en-dash.
6. If you want the caption above the table, use `\captionabove` (because of `scrbook`): there *should* be space between the caption and the table.

The picture shows also the page boundaries:

[image]

The code (with just the necessary packages):

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  oneside,
  chapterprefix=true,
  sfdefaults=false
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % why inches?

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\captionabove{Comparison between smartphone and MPU+MCU based monitoring}
\label{swa_tab:2}       % Give a unique label

\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l @{}}
\toprule
Features & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Smartphone} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MCU+MPU}\\
\midrule
Device Type & General purpose & Dedicated \\
\addlinespace
Cost & High (US\$100 or more) &  Low (US\$10 or less)\\
\addlinespace
Form Factor & 6--7 inches & 2--3 inches\\
\addlinespace
Power Consumption & More than 5 watt & less than 1 watt\\
\addlinespace
Device Integration & Very Difficult & Easy to integrate\\
\addlinespace
Ease of use & Difficult for seniors & Easy for seniors\\
\addlinespace
Durability \& parts & Fragile \& costly spare & Durable \& Cheap\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You might want to extend the table to cover the whole textwidth; in this case, use `tabular*`, but I don't see a real improvement (to be honest, the table looks worse):

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  oneside,
  chapterprefix=true,
  sfdefaults=false
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % why inches?

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\captionabove{Comparison between smartphone and MPU+MCU based monitoring}
\label{swa_tab:2}       % Give a unique label

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l l l @{}}
\toprule
Features & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Smartphone} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{MCU+MPU}\\
\midrule
Device Type & General purpose & Dedicated \\
\addlinespace
Cost & High (US\$100 or more) &  Low (US\$10 or less)\\
\addlinespace
Form Factor & 6--7 inches & 2--3 inches\\
\addlinespace
Power Consumption & More than 5 watt & less than 1 watt\\
\addlinespace
Device Integration & Very Difficult & Easy to integrate\\
\addlinespace
Ease of use & Difficult for seniors & Easy for seniors\\
\addlinespace
Durability \& parts & Fragile \& costly spare & Durable \& Cheap\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Finally, the first realization (not extended) with no `\addlinespace` command, which I find the most appealing.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- You define four columns but use only three
- `tabularx` table should has at least one `X` column type, you hasn't any
- possible solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt, la4paper,
                istof=totoc,
                oneside,
                chapterprefix=true,
                sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe,      % remove this option in the real document
            margin=1in]{geometry}
%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
%\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx, ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
% For tables use
\begin{table}
\centering
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Comparison between smartphone and MPU+MCU based monitoring}
\label{swa_tab:2}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{L{1}L{1.2}L{0.8}}
    \toprule
\thead{Features} 
    &   \thead{ Smartphone} 
        &   \thead{MCU+MPU}     \\
\midrule
\textbf{Device Type} & General purpose & Dedicated \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Cost} & High~(US\$100 or more) &  Low~(US\$10 or less)\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Form Factor} & 6-7 inches & 2-3 inches\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Power Consumption} & More than 5 watt & less than 1 watt\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Device Integration} &Very Difficult& Easy to integrate\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Ease of use}& Difficult for seniors & Easy for seniors\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Durability \& parts} & Fragile\&costly spare & Durable\&Cheap\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray lines show text are borders}

** Addendum:**
However, if you willing to use `tabularray` package for writing of table, code of your table become quite shorter:

```
\documentclass[11pt, la4paper,
                istof=totoc,
                oneside,
                chapterprefix=true,
                sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe,      % remove this option in the real document
            margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}  % it load booktabs packagew ....

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparison between smartphone and MPU+MCU based monitoring}
\label{swa_tab:2}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tblr}{width=0.9\linewidth,
             colspec = {X[l, font=\bfseries] X[1.2,l]X[0.8,l]},
             row{1}  = {font=\normalfont} 
            }
    \toprule
Features    &   Smartphone  &   MCU+MPU     \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Device Type} & General purpose & Dedicated \\
\textbf{Cost} & High~(US\$100 or more) &  Low~(US\$10 or less)\\
\textbf{Form Factor} & 6-7 inches & 2-3 inches\\
\textbf{Power Consumption} & More than 5 watt & less than 1 watt\\
\textbf{Device Integration} &Very Difficult& Easy to integrate\\
\textbf{Ease of use}& Difficult for seniors & Easy for seniors\\
\textbf{Durability \& parts} & Fragile\&costly spare & Durable\&Cheap\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mico and Zarco. Both the answers will solve my problem. However, Mico has helped me a lot today with other problems. So my vote goes with his answer. But I am upvoting Zarko also.